# Use VBA "With" statement to refer to the object itself?

Tags: excel, vba

If I use the "With" keyword in VBA, I have to access attributes/methods in the objects which "With" is locked on. But, can I refer to the object **itself** within the "With" statement?

F.e., suppose i have a that function takes a range as input. I also lock "With" on a specific range, for editing multiple attributes in the range:

```
Function ViewCellColor(inputrange As Range)
    ' This function takes a range as input
    MsgBox inputrange.Interior.Color
End Function

Sub Test()
    With Range("A1")
        .Select
        .Interior.Color = vbRed
        .Value = 10
        .Font.Bold = True
        Run ViewCellColor(Range("A1")) ' Use range as input to function
    End With
End Sub
```

Here, I want to pass the range itself to the function, but I here have to **re-write** the range reference (A1) for the function argument passing. Is it possible to avoid double-typing the range reference here?

Comment: No but you could do `.Range("A1")` or `.Cells(1)`.

Comment: No need for the `.Select`

Comment: urdearboy: I know, it was just for the example.

Answer (score 5):

You can't, unless the object exposes a member that returns itself.

```
Public Property Get Self() As WhateverThatClassIs
    Set Self = Me
End Property
```

In the case of `Excel.Range`, the `Cells` property should work:

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A1") '<~ always qualify Range with the sheet you're working with
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .Value = 10
    .Font.Bold = True
    ViewCellColor .Cells
End With
```

Note that the `Range.Cells` property does not have any parameters - when we do `someRange.Cells(x)`, the `(x)` subscript goes against the hidden `Range.[_Default]` member of the `Range` object that's returned by the `Cells` property.

Because it's not returning anything, `ViewCellColor` should be a `Sub` procedure, and its `inputRange` parameter should be passed `ByVal` (the implicit and unfortunate implicit default is `ByRef`) because that scope has no business re-assigning that particular `Range` reference.

---

Alternatively, you could declare and assign a local `Range` variable, and use it to qualify the repeated member calls instead:

```
Dim Cell As Range
Set Cell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

Cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
Cell.Value = 10
Cell.Font.Bold = True

ViewCellColor Cell
```

Like a `With` block, it's much better than dereferencing a `Range` on the `ActiveSheet` for each individual instruction.

You could also get to skip a few keystrokes if you reference that variable in a `With` expression:

```
Dim Cell As Range
Set Cell = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

With Cell
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .Value = 10
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

ViewCellColor Cell
```

Caveat: programming is mostly about *reading* code; spending these few extra keystrokes when *writing* it can easily pay off in the end. Avoid nesting `With` blocks, and keep them small - they can subtly complicate matters when things go awry: you usually don't want to accidentally re-enter a `With` block with a `Resume` statement in your error handling, for example.

Comment: Ok, but if I would work with other data object types, there is no way to make a reference in "With" to correspond to "Me" in f.e. VBA:s event handlar techniques? I.e., to the "current" object itself, not its attributes?

Comment: `Me` is only ever local (see my user profile), the concept of a "current object" does not exist outside a local scope =) ...if the interface isn't exposing it, ...then you need a local variable. `With` is over-rated though. Just spell out the local variable!